# Watch command linux

Tags: linux, watch

when executing watch command to check a bunch of errors, the window is not able to show the rest of the errors when it reaches a certain amount of rows. I want to be able to see all rows being generated using watch command, how can I do it??

Comment: Use a smaller font.

Answer (score 3):

The manual for `watch` explicitly states:

> > watch runs command repeatedly, displaying its output (the first screenfull).

So, if that is not what you want, don't use `watch`.

Alternatively, use (in bash):

```
while :; do
    clear
    # The command that you want to use to view
    sleep 2  # 2 secs is the default for watch
done
```